# unable to find error with array_merge

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to insert batch query in code igniter, I am not able to make array_merge work. Don't know whats the problem. M getting blank array.

```
        $epin_amt = $this->input->post('amount');
            $qty = $this->input->post('qty');
            $data = array();
            for ($i = 0; $i <= $qty; $i++) {
                $array = array(
                    'epin'   => mt_rand(100000, 999999),
                    'amount' => $epin_amt,
                );
             array_merge($data, $array);
            }
print_r($data) ; // Produce : array( )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are merging the arrays but it's not done by reference so you're throwing the resulting array away. `array_push()` it instead, that will keep adding the arrays to your `$data` array:

```
<?php
$epin_amt = 10;
$qty = 20;
$data = array();
for ($i = 0; $i <= $qty; $i++) {
    $array = array(
        'epin'   => mt_rand(100000, 999999),
        'amount' => $epin_amt,
    );
 array_push($data, $array);
}
print_r($data) ;
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to assign the merged array back to your $data variable:

```
<?php

$epin_amt = /*$this->input->post('amount')*/ 5;
$qty = /*$this->input->post('qty')*/6;

$data = array();
for ($i = 0; $i <= $qty; $i++) {
    $array = array(
        'epin'   => mt_rand(100000, 999999),
        'amount' => $epin_amt,
    );
 $data = array_merge($data, $array);
}

print_r($data) ;
```

Comment: But this time I am getting only 1 array . `Array ( [epin] => 653552 [amount] => 100 ) `

Comment: Stack overflow recommends that you provide an expected result. There's no way I can know what you expect now, because looking at your code, all I see is a single `$epin_amount`, and a single `$qty` value. Please revise your question to show the expected result, because as it is, based on the wording of your question, you are getting answers that are correct, they just don't meet your needs.

Answer (score 2):

[array_merge](http://php.net/array_merge) returns `array`. You need something like this:

```
$result = array_merge($data, $array);
```